# how does usage of braces change the value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the below Javascript code:

```
const product = await productsRepo.getOne(req.params.id);
console.log(product);
console.log({product});
```

Output from first console.log.

```
{ title: 'hey12up', price: 1234, image: '', id: 'b6ff5da7' }
```

Output from second console.log:

```
{
  product: { title: 'hey12up', price: 1234, image: '', id: 'b6ff5da7' }
}
```

Though I understand that in the second output, product is a key and the value is an object (which are further key-value pairs), I dont understand how this conversion is done?

Just by enclosing the object name "product" inside braces, what is happening? Is there any technical term for this?

Comment: `{product}` is shorthand for `{product: product}`. You are just outputting an object in which key `product` has value of variable named `product`

Comment: Thanks!! got it now